# How to Power 2 devices at different voltages with the same set of power source(batteries)

Tags: batteries, parallel, series

I'm just curious if it's possible to power 2 devices at different voltages with a set of batteries while making sure that the 2 devices makes use of all the batteries. I have here an illustration of the connection that I would like to get verified. [image: Each battery is rated ***n*** volts]

Each battery is rated ***n*** volts

I used dashed lines in 2n volts connection for ease of seeing. 
I want to power each device with 4n volts and 2n volts[image: An Alternative Illustration]

An Alternative Illustration^

The solution that I propose is to connect 4 batteries in series first to power 1 device. Then since there can be 2 sets of batteries in series already I can connect these sets in parallel for the Voltage to **not** add up. However, just by looking at  the circuit I think some portions are actually shorted.

Any help would be appreciated. *Please don't be  harsh if this is a dumb question.*

Comment: Can you draw batteries in a straight chain, it's so difficult to imagine what you have drawn.

Comment: Yes, you can do that but batteries that power two devices will die faster.

Comment: @LongPham https://scontent.fmnl9-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/34101116_2132940810361720_4821723852075696128_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=10ce936b3d8d1591a05fed427e175cb7&oe=5B7C5C06

Comment: I have done it. My bad

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: are the two devices real or imaginary? .... what are they?

Comment: If you follow the dashed lines in either of your proposed circuits, you will see that they produce sort circuits around pairs of batteries.  I think the only solution is to use a DC-DC converter to step down the full battery voltage to the lower level that your lower voltage devices require.

Comment: @jsotola These are arbitrary/variable "devices". Just considering them as loads with some resistance may be best I guess. This is just a theoretical view I should say.

Comment: @PeterBennett I guess you're right . but What about just adding a resistor?

Comment: @jsotola No it's not a school assignment :)

Comment: A resistor is not good, as the voltage drop will depend on the current drawn by the load.  A linear voltage regulator such as a 7812 will provide a constant voltage, but will waste significant power (and get hot!).  A DC-DC converter or switching regulator (same thing, different name) would waste much less power than a linear regulator.

Comment: `theoretical view` .... put two `2nV` in series and just ignore one ... lol ........ no, i got nothing, sorry

Comment: :( It still looks awful.

Comment: Gah! 4 nanovolt? No! 4n V, not 4 nV. Please clean up your schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Your attempt to power a 4n load, and and 2n load from balanced batteries, shorts out each 2n battery.

You have two (or three) options.

a) Power the 4n load, and a 4n->2n converter to power the 2n load. This could be a linear regulator if the power level is low enough for you to not worry about the inefficiency and heat. Better though would be a buck regulator.

b) Configure the batteries as 2n, and power the 2n load, and a 2n->4n boost converter. Choose (a) or (b) depending on which load draws more power, or the convenience of having a buck or boost converter to hand.

c) Power the 2n load from a battery tap, and tolerate the consequences of the imbalance (replacing batteries earlier, or charging differently)

d) Power the 2n load from a switchable battery tap, so you spend 50% of the time powered from the 'top' batteries, and 50% of the time from the 'bottom' ones. Obviously you cannot common the grounds if using it like this.

e) Use a 2n set and a 4n set of batteries. You need more batteries, but get complete freedom.

Ok, so 5 options.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't adding a pair of diodes solve the issue? If the current isn't something massive I think it would be fine no?[image: Professional drawing]

Comment: no <+ extra letters to make up the comment length>

Comment: @Neil_UK how so?

Comment: Hello Red, and welcome. If you don't describe the issue, we cannot answer to your question.